# How to update BATCH Version

Tags: file, batch-file, version

recently i have been programming in batch and came upon a dilemma,  my Batch File version is 5.1.2600 and the version i need to run some commands is 6.  Is there any way to update BATCH?

-Thank-you in advance

Comment: what!?...you mean the cmd version?, im guessing ur on XP then? what command do you need?

Comment: I think 5.1.2600 is your Windows version maybe. Type "systeminfo" at a command prompt and see what it says. If this is the case then you need a newer version of Windows! I'm running Windows 7 and my OS version is 6.1.7601

Comment: @mclaassen its the OS version.. try "cmd -v"

Comment: @JoeDF which just shows the OS version which you can also get from running systeminfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Batch Version, That's your OS version.

If you specify the "commands" you need, we could find alternatives, since most of these "commands" are actually executables.

heres a few:

- http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchtools.php
- [Bill Stewart - Shell Scripting Toolkit](https://westmesatech.com/?page_id=26)

Comment: oh, well the command, i think it's a command, i have tried to use is "echo %name% %point% %date% %time% >> score.txt"   It is sopposed to send the data from a little game i have made into a text file, like a scoring system but it seems not to be working.

Comment: well it should work?, your're trying to append text to a file?

Comment: Sorry about that first comment, first time using Stack Overflow XD

Comment: no its ok, but what is it that your trying to do? store text in a file?

Comment: Yes i am trying to send text to a file, the file already exists in the same directory as the script.

Comment: It is not working, the file just stays blank when i open it up again.  Could it be a problem the the %name% variable i have, is that variable reserved for the system?  Also i don't know if this maters but my system is quite weird and won't let me run a .bat file by double clicking the icon, so i must open cmd and drag the icon in there to get the full directory then run it from cmd.

Comment: Well i don't know if this helps but here is a code snipit from my program.  set /p save=Would you like to submit a score? [Y/N]:
if %save%==n goto begin
if %save%==y cls
echo.
echo You scored: %point%
echo.
set /p name=Type name:
echo Your text here >> score.txt

Comment: sounds like a permission problem. What is the path of score.txt?

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\Desktop\memoryGame\score.txt

Comment: weird... Does something like 'echo blabla >>score.txt' work from command line? Any error messages?

Comment: Nope, nothing.  Not even a error message.  I think my computer has a good number of viruses though, those might be causing some problems.

Comment: I would not expect this kind of problems from a virus. Please open a new command window. Type 'echo blabla >test.txt'  Then type 'type test.txt'. Does it show you 'blabla?

Comment: Yes it does does me blabla

Comment: And i tried that with score.txt and it showed the data i put in.  Just where would that file be then?

Comment: ok... I think, your batchfile is working well and appends the text to score.txt - but another score.txt. try 'dir /s c:\score.txt'. I'm quite sure it will find more than one. (this will need some minutes)

Comment: Ok it's working now!  Thanks a bunch.  I found like 5 score.txt's so i put in the whole directory of the score.txt i wanted it to save too.  In the past i never had to do that.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart ahaha, feels like a programmer's version of a cameo ;)

Answer (score 2):

Batch is an operating system feature. The version number you've mentioned (5.1.2600) means it's Windows XP. Version 6 designates Vista, 6.1 designates Windows 7, and 6.2 designates Windows 8. So no, you can't *update batch*, but you can upgrade your OS. Just run your batch file on the OS whose features you require.